# What are the counterparts of scalars and vectors called in other algebraic structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

As far as I understand, an element of a field is called a scalar and an element of a vector space is called a vector.

What's the scalar's counterpart in a semiring and a ring? And what's the vector's counterpart in a semimodule and a module?

To go one step further, are there names for element of a boolean algebra and a 'ring over boolean algebra', if such a thing exists?

To clarify, my question is only about terminology, what's the agreed-upon name for these elements.

Comment: For a module, elements of the ring are still called scalars

Comment: As you say yourself "an element of a vector space". For an algebra $A$, $x\in A$ is called an element of $A$, too. So the counterpart to "vector" here is "element".

Comment: Cool, I was wondering if there was a more specialized name but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: For some other structures there are indeed other names, e.g., for categories. There we have *objects* in a category, and morphisms. Groups, fields, rings, algebras etc. have elements.